# Acces Denied in CodeIgniter using Linux

Tags: linux, codeigniter

Why am i getting a 403 Error. when I tried copying my work on a linux os and put it on my lampp folder. Originally my project is made from Windows. I tried changing the permission using this sudo chmod 765 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs. But it still won't work.

Comment: 403 could mean a lot of things.. what user is your lampp running as? Also, the permission bit 765 looks a little odd to me. Please visit: http://permissions-calculator.org/

Comment: @alok it says here mint

Comment: ok.. I edited that comment to add a link.. please have a look and change your chmod <permission_bit> to what you think is right. I feel it should be 755. Crude method is to set it to 777.

Comment: @alok but they say 777 is not a good practice. I tried using 777 but now it says 404 Page Not Found. Even though the file exists

Comment: I've given an answer, but you may also check out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/327588/cannot-access-copied-folder-in-htdocs-of-lampp-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are not too familiar with linux in general. 
Here are the two commands that might be of help:

```
$ sudo chown mint:users -R /opt/lampp
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp
```

First command will set owner of the entire lampp as your regular user, which I'm assuming is "mint" from your comments.

Second command will set following security/permission bits on your folder:
User  : RWX
Group : R-X
Others: R-X

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the /opt/lampp/htdocs directory so that the user you are logged in as has permission to write. You also need to ensure that what you write in there can be read by whatever web server LAMPP uses (I'm not familiar with LAMP unfortunately.)

First you need to look at who is owning /opt/lampp/htdocs:

```
$ ls -lah /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Should return something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 lampp www 4096 2015-05-22 12:43 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

The first bit (dwrxr-xr-x) is the file permissions. "lampp" is the owner of the directory, and "www" is the group-owner of the directory. You need to note this one.

First off let's sort the group. If the group is anything except "root" then all is well and good and you can skip this section:

If it's "root" it will need changing to something more sensible. Make a new group for it to belong to. Then change the group on the directory:

```
$ sudo groupadd www
$ sudo chgrp -R www /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Now you need to make the web server run as the group www. If the web server is Apache then you should check the /etc/apache/httpd.conf file and edit the "Group" setting accordingly

```
sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

We need to address the permissions on the directory. We want to use the "setgid" bit.

```
$ sudo chmod 2775 /opt/lampp/htdocs
$ ls -ld /opt/lampp/htdocs
drwxrwsr-x 4 lampp www 4096 2015-05-22 12:43 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

You see the permissions have now changed somewhat. Let's explain these.

```
The first letter is the file type. In this case "d" is for Directory.
The next three, "rwx" are the permissions the owner (lampp) has on the directort. r = read, w=write and x=see the directory contents.
The next three, "rws" are for the group-owner (www), but you notice the x in this case is actually an s - we will come to that in a moment.
The last three, "r-x", are for everybody else. That is read, and see the content of the directory. No writing.
```

The "s" in the group permissions is called the "setgid" bit. This is a special permission which causes any files created in the directory to inherit the group-owner from the directory itself. So if user "fred" in group "users" makes a file in there it would be owned by "fred" in group "www". This is very useful for a shared area where multiple people all read and write the same files.

Now, you need to add your user into  group

```
$ sudo usermod -aG www malyy
```

Replace "www" with the group-owner of the /opt/lampp/htdocs directory you noted near the beginning.

You will need to log out and in again for this change to take effect - your group memberships are read at login time